# "mask cannot be scalar" in keras.max() function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

When I used Keras.max(box_scores,keep_dims=False) in an assignment, I got an error, and it was "mask cannot be scalar".
But when I used Keras.max(box_scores,axis=-1,keep_dims=False) , I got the result. But I don't understand it.What is the purpose of axis=-1 in this function to correct this error?

```
box_scores = box_confidence * box_class_probs
box_classes = K.argmax(box_scores, axis=-1) 
box_class_scores = K.max(box_scores,keepdims=False)
filtering_mask = ((box_class_scores)>=threshold)
scores = tf.boolean_mask(box_class_scores,filtering_mask ,name="filtering_scores")
boxes = tf.boolean_mask(boxes,filtering_mask ,name="filtering_boxes")
classes = tf.boolean_mask(box_classes,filtering_mask ,name="filtering_classes")
```

Here, box_confidence = tensor of shape (19, 19, 5, 1),
    boxes -- tensor of shape (19, 19, 5, 4),
    box_class_probs -- tensor of shape (19, 19, 5, 80),
    and threshold -- real value, if [ highest class probability score < threshold], then get rid of the corresponding box.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `max` function `axis` parameter specifies a list of dimensions (or one dimension or `None` for all dimensions) over which max is computed. When negative integers are used they are interpreted similarly to Python negative indicies of array (i.e. `-1` means the last dimension, `-2` - second from last, etc.).

So when you're not specifying `axis` argument the default value `None` is used resulting in scalar output (i.e. maximum of all values in the tensor). When you are specifying `axis=-1` only the last dimension is reduced so from tensor of shape `(a,b,c,d)` you'll get a tensor of shape `(a,b,c)`.

Strangely, `keras` documentation doesn't specify it here [max reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/max).